# Is there a method to add multiple properties to HtmlTextWriterStyle?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am creating new elements for a webpage at run-time and I have code like this:

```
      var dynDiv = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("Div") {ID = "dynDiv"};
      dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Red");
      dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position, "absolute; left: 500px; top: 500px");
      dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "30px");
      dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "300px");
      dynDiv.InnerHtml = "New Object";
      PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(dynDiv);
```

Is there a shorthand method to adding these value? I.e. something like:

```
dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle {BackgroundColor = "Red", Position = "absolute; left: 500px; top: 500px", Height = "30px", Width="300px"});
```

Or any other easier way that anyone can suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, you could use collection initializer to write your code this way:

```
var dynDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("Div")
{
    ID = "dynDiv",
    Style =
    {
        { HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "Red" },
        { HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position, "absolute; left: 500px; top: 500px" },
        { HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "30px" },
        { HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "300px" }
    },
    InnerHtml = "New Object"
};
```

Unfortunately, this code won't compile, because [`CssStyleCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable`](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/786670/cssstylecollection-should-implement-ienumerable), which is a requirement for collection initializers.

Comment: OK, I'll have to stick with writing it the way I am. It just seems very verbose. As you state, there's normally shorter ways to do this type of thing.